# Login Page Username and Password cannot be posted (PHP)

Tags: php

Username and password not appear on `Page 2.PHP` although I post it to `Page2.PHP`

Page1.PHP

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="Page2.php">
<input type="text" name="txtLogin">
<input type="password" name="txtPWD">
<input type="submit" name="btnSub" value="go">
</form>
```

Page2.PHP

```
<?php 
if(isset($_REQUEST['txtLogin'])) 
{ 
session_start();   
$_SESSION['login']=$login; 
} 

if(isset($_SESSION['login'])) 
header('Location: detail.php'); 
else 
header('Location: index.html'); 

?>
```

Comment: You do not seem to assign $login;  any value, or code is missing in your post

Comment: There is no `echo`-command on Page2.PHP. So there can't appear anything or you didn't post all your code.

Comment: to check what you get use `print_r($_POST);`

Comment: Better to explicitly use $_POST instead of $_REQUEST, because of http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order

Comment: Set your error display to show you warning messages and you'll see what the problem is -- you'll get a warning about `undefined variable $login on line 5`, which should be a sufficient clue to help you see what the problem is.

Comment: Sorry oktopus, ya i missed out echo. But i put also nothing is displayed

Answer (score 0):

put this on page2.php

```
   if(isset($_POST['txtLogin']) && isset($_POST['txtPWD']))
    {
        //get values & do other scripts like saving values on sessions
        $user = $_POST['txtLogin'];
        $pass = $_POST['txtPWD'];
        echo $user.'<br>'.$pass;

    }
    else
    {
        //event here
    }
```

Comment: I have made the changes you posted here. But after filled and press submit button on  Page1.PHP, and nothing is being displayed on Page2.PHP. Even is put echo "Print to check"; before   if(isset($_POST['txtLogin']) && isset($_POST['txtPWD'])).. wonder why?

Comment: maybe the problem is in your apache server?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
$_SESSION['login']=$login;
```

You are using the `$login` variable, but it isn't actually being set anywhere.

A few lines further up, we see that the login name is actually in `$_REQUEST['txtLogin']`, not `$login`. So you should be using that.

```
$_SESSION['login']=$_REQUEST['txtLogin'];
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

Check settings: enable_post_data_reading, request_order, variables_order, gpc_order  on http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php

Comment: -1 because (a) this should have been a comment, (b) someone else already said the same thing in the comments (so I guess you're just copying from them?), and (c) this has nothing to do the actual cause of the problem.

Comment: This is not a copy, couse it's deeper than comment. I've scan all settings for impact on POST... But you right it was not an answer :^ )